# Why does a comment give a html_safe error when it's at the end of the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had two (large) pieces of code that were identical, with the only difference being, one ended with

```
<% end %>
```

as the last line, and the other ending with

```
<% end # finish loop_x %>
```

The second produced the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass):
    13:       <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    14:         <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    15:       <% end %>
    16:       <%= yield %>
    17:       <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    18:       <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    19:     </div>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in '..
```

But what is strange is this error only occurs if <% end # %> is the last line in the page. If I put the comment inside an end statement partway through the page, there is no error. And ending with just <% end %> works fine.

I am using rails 3.2.3, but this also occured in 3.2.2

Comment: could you try putting the '%>' on the next line (after the comment) ?

Comment: I assume the same data is being returned each time?